# Prolog. Difficult beginnings

Tags: prolog

At the beginning: I am beginner in Prolog but I have to admit, the language is curious because of the fact other paradigm.

```
find_kth_e(X, [X|_], 1).
find_kth_e(X, [_|T], K) :- K > 1, K1 is K-1, find_kth_e(X, T, K1). 

?-  find_kth_e(X, [1,2,3,4,5], 3).
X = 3 ;
false.
```

1. What is `find_kth_e`? Function? Relation? ( Yeah, I know that a function is a relation).
2. The result is `3`. And it is ok. But why the second result is `false`?

Let's consider a modified version:

```
find_kth_e(X, [X|_], 1).
find_kth_e(X, [_|T], K) :- K > 1, K1 is K-1, find_kth_e(_, T, K1). 

?-  find_kth_e(X, [1,2,3,4,5], 3).
X = 3 ;
false.
```

The only difference is in line: `find_kth_e(X, [_|T], K) :- K > 1, K1 is K-1, find_kth_e(_, T, K1).`. I replaced `X` with `_`. And now:

```
?-  find_kth_e(X, [1,2,3,4,5], 3).

true ;
false.
```

The answer is true and false. Why there is no `3`? After all, the result should be returned by first version of function- I mean     `find_kth_e(X, [X|_], 1)`. So, the fact that I replaced `X` with `_` should doesn't matter.

Please explain .

Comment: Technically, there is no functions in Prolog. It's *predicates*. `false` means that the search did not find any satisfying unification for the variables.

Comment: As @EugeneSh. says, Prolog has *predicates*. A *predicate* may have one or more *predicate clauses* (yours has two). A *predicate* defines a *relation* between its arguments. In your last example, the result is "true" but there is a *choice point*. Your `;` input told Prolog to check for more solutions, and Prolog came back with "false" since there were no more solutions.

Comment: The answer is not "true and false". It is `true ; false.` which means true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @EugeneSh. says, Prolog has *predicates*. A *predicate* may have one or more *predicate clauses* (yours has two). A *predicate* defines a *relation* between its arguments.

```
?-  find_kth_e(X, [1,2,3,4,5], 3).
X = 3 ;
false.
```

In this example, you queried whether `X` is the 3rd argument of list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Prolog succeeded with `X = 3`. But there was a *choice point* in your predicate, meaning Prolog encountered a place in the code before it succeeded where an alternative decision could be explored. When you pressed `;`, you told Prolog to explore that alternative (Prolog *backtracks*). Prolog found there were no more solutions after `X = 3`, so Prolog says "false".

When you replaced `X` with `_` you indicated that you didn't care what the first argument is:

```
?-  find_kth_e(_, [1,2,3,4,5], 3).
true ;
false.
```

As in the first query, Prolog succeeded in finding a 3rd element, but you indicated that you didn't care what that element is. So Prolog succeeds and says only "true". And, as before, the choice point is there. Your `;` tells Prolog to *backtrack* to the choice point and it found no more solutions, so ultimately shows "false".

Here's another little test you can do to show success versus failure:

```
?- find_kth_e(X, [a,b,c,d,e], 3), write('Success!'), nl.
Success!
X = c ;
false.
```

Since the `find_kth_e/3` succeeded, Prolog continued to the `write/1` statement which wrote "Success!" and then showed `X = c` (Prolog shows all the variables that result in success after the entire clause finishes executing).

Here's a failure case:

```
?- find_kth_e(X, [a,b,c,d,e], 6), write('Success!'), nl.
false.

?-
```

`find_kth_e/3` could not find a 6th element, so it failed. Prolog did not continue and do the `write/1` due to the failure of the prior statement, and you can see "Success!" was not displayed.

Comment: "As in the first query, Prolog succeeded in finding a 3rd element, but you indicated that you didn't care what that element is.". Yes, indeed I don't care in **that** clause, but in other `find_kth_e(X, [X|_], 1)` I care.

Comment: @J.Doe and, indeed, in the `find_kth_e(X, [X|_], 1)` would respond properly with `X` because you *do* care. In that clause, `_` means you don't care what the tail of list `[X|_]` is because it isn't relevant to the solution for that clause. If that were your only predicate clause and you queried, `find_kth_e(X, [a,b,c], 1)` you would get `X = a`.